# .NET 2010 custom control, multiline String property to be edited in the designer

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls

I'm writing a custom control and I want to add a "MessageText" property of type String:

```
<Browsable(True),
  DefaultValue(""),
  Category("CustomControls"),
  Description("Blah."),
  DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
  Public Property MessageText As String
```

The MessageText property is a multiline text, and the user must be able to set the text using the designer. The problem is that the designer doesn't allow to enter a newline directly for a string property.

I want the same behaviour as the system TextBox's Text property, where you can click on the down arrow and write lines in the small text-editor that appears:

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the declaration for the TextBoxBase.Text property:

```
[Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor)), Localizable(true)]
public override string Text
{
    // etc..  
}
```

The [Editor] attribute is what you need.  There is hassle if you also use .NET 4.0 (note the version string).  It is better to use the alternative version of the constructor.  Project + Add Reference, select System.Design.  Make it look like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
        [Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        public string MessageText {
            // etc... 
        }
```