# Textbox dropdown bubble when text goes over visual space?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, datagridviewtextboxcell

I looking for a way to add what would look like a drop down box when the user reaches the end of the visible space of a textbox. the drop down would then show what they have already typed pulse what there still typing tell they hit enter. Any ideas? The bigger pitcher is to add whatever method we come up with to a GridViewTextbox where space is limited in a row however the data they enter can be much longer then the box. The idea is to keep user from getting lost in what there typing and can provide easy review and edit. something like this but pops up when you enters then gos back on leave but just be for text as 'enter' will move the user to the next control aka enter as tab

It won't let me post the image I was talking about so use this like as a refrence [.NET 2010 custom control, multiline String property to be edited in the designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759487/net-2010-custom-control-multiline-string-property-to-be-edited-in-the-designer)

Comment: by 'visible space', do you mean when the text scrolls?  how do you intend to detect that? the toosltripdropdown will work as the "bubble"

Comment: 'Visible space' the end of the txtbox showen on the form so ya I guess you could say when it scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

In the ASP.NET there is control which suits the need.I hope it helps
It is

```
    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender
                                    runat="server" 
                                    BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx"
                                    ID="autoComplete1" 
                                    TargetControlID="targetID"
                                    ServicePath="Give the Path of the web service"
                                    ServiceMethod="Name of the ID "
                                    MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
                                    CompletionInterval="500"
                                    EnableCaching="true"
                                    CompletionSetCount="10"
                                    DelimiterCharacters=";, :"
                                    ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true"
       />
```

Comment: Humm good Idea if I was doing an ASP page. Mybe I asked this in the wrong place. But this will help on a side project im working on.

Comment: How about using the `TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a ToolTip control to show a popup message to the user. I've read your question three times now and I'm still not sure entirely what it is you're asking.

Comment: I guess its hard to explain it would be like the text box temporally turns multi line and resize so the user can see everything entered and then when they leave the box it goes back to single line and resizes to default. But there's got to be a better way.

Comment: Oh, you can do that. You know the height of each line (TextBox.Font) and you know how many lines there are. You can just set the height of the textbox to equal the number of lines times the height, as long as it is in focus. Let me know if I'm being unclear.

Comment: No that sounds close check the link out it has an image close to what I would like to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759487/net-2010-custom-control-multiline-string-property-to-be-edited-in-the-designer